# From which applications do these "S" symbol and balloon like notifications respectively belong to?

Tags: app-icons

[image]

Please help me with the (S) looking icon and the hot air balloon icon.  What apps are they. Thanks

Comment: Do you not see corresponding notifications when you pull down from the status bar?

Comment: No. I need someone to figure it out. I've tried for days

Comment: Ok I got one symbol for you, its qihoo 360 mobile security (s) shaped icon

Answer (score 2):

The S shaped icon is [Qihoo 360 Mobile Security application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qihoo.security).

Here is the source to confirm : [Qihoo 360 Security - Antivirus Boost (for Android)](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2468630,00.asp)

The grey bubble like or hot air balloon  notification is not very clear, but while I couldn't deduce from which app it comes from, I suspect its from a live wallpaper of some sort. Check related settings to confirm.

Comment: Thank you. Please let me know about the hot air balloon one if you can. Thanks

Comment: Sure @Rob, will do